# Eclipselink: Difference between static and dynamic weaving

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I use eclipselink 2.6.3 and have the following code:

```
public Temp getTemp() {
    EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
    String queryString="SELECT a FROM Temp a";
    EntityGraph<Temp> eg = em.createEntityGraph(Temp.class);
    eg.addAttributeNodes("id");
    //eg.addAttributeNodes("name");
    Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", eg);
    List<Temp> items=query.getResultList();
    em.close();// ENTITYMANAGER IS CLOSED 
    return items.get(0);
}

public void temp(){
    Temp temp=getTemp();
    System.out.println("id:"+temp.getId());
    System.out.println("name:"+temp.getName());
}
```

**Situation 1:**
When weaving is static (`<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>` + de.empulse.eclipselink weaving plugin) and we do temp.getName() onemore SQL query is executed and necessary data is loaded. In spite of the fact we did close entity manager. I expected to get exception at temp.getName().

**Situation 2:**
However, when weaving is dynamic (`<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>`) I get exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl not found by com.temp [57]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.temp.Temp._persistence_checkFetched(Temp2.java)
at com.temp.Temp._persistence_get_name(Temp2.java)
at com.temp.Temp.getName(Temp.java:44)
```

How to explain this difference? Is this a bug?

Comment: seems as an OSGi related issue to me. You should import `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa` and also make sure that eclipse link does export it

Answer (score 1):

If you running your application as desktop(standalone) , tomcat or jetty, then dynamic weaving is not available by default, and lazy fetch is not supported , all lazy fetch will be treated as eager.

Regarding the static weaving, the below is from eclipselink tutorial:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial

> Limitations to JPA
>   As Tomcat is not a Java EE 5 compatible server,
>   there are some limitiations to JPA. No dynamic weaving
>   (instrumentation)
>   - static weaving of entities is still available via
>   EclipseLink No @EJB injection of a session bean (containing the
>   EntityManager) is available
>    - use the persistence factory and manager
>   directly No @PersistenceContext injection of a container managed
>   persistence unit is available
>   - use
>   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(JTA_PU_NAME)

to make your entities support static weaving :
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving